# How do I pass pipe to a C app as a file?

Tags: c++, c, file, pipe, file-descriptor

I would like to do something like this:

```
nc localhost 1234 | myapp
```

But I would like myapp to be able to see the pipe passed from the first part of the command as a file.

For example:

```
int main() {
    File *fp;
    fp = /* get pointer file which is the pipe passed as "nc localhost 1234" */
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Just read from `stdin`. The output of the last command is piped to `stdin` of the next command.

Comment: Is this a must or is there a more generic way? What if I wanted to write to the descriptor?

Comment: `fileno(stdin)` returns you the descriptor for `stdin`, or just use the macro `STDIN_FILENO`.

Comment: What if I wanted to send some data to this pipe and some others to stdout/stdin and do not want to mix up std* data with the pipe's data?

Comment: The shell intercepts the pipe symbol and creates the actual pipe and doesn't tell your program about it. If you want some kind of similar functionality in your program, you'll have to use another character and parse it and implement it yourself.

Comment: @hebbo the standard behaviour of the shell for `a | b` is to connect stdout of a to sstdin of b. If you don't want that, then you have to create the processes yourself using `fork` and create `pipes` yourself (with `pipe()`), etc.

Comment: Are you using C or C++?  You have the C++ tag, so you should read from `std::cin`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews either way is fine. My code base has both C and C++ code. I need to know these details to write a new small tool to be added to the code base. I have both options available.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you considered using a named pipe?  They are like pipes, one directional, but they have names.  If you wanted two directions you could just make two pipes.  You make the pipes like this:

```
mkfifo /dir/to_prog
mkfifo /dir/from_prog
```

Then the output of one program can be separately piped to the second and the name of the pipe can be used like a normal filename:

```
nc localhost 1234 > /dir/to_prog
myapp -i /dir/to_prog -o /dir/from_prog
cat < /dir/from_prog
```

Except that those three commands could even be issued in three separate shells.  myapp.c could look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int iFd, oFd, opt;

    while (opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:")) != -1) {

        switch (opt) {

        ...

        case 'i':  iFd = open(optarg, O_RDONLY); break;
        case 'o':  oFd = open(optarg, O_WRONLY); break;

        ...
        }
    }

    ...

    read(iFd, inBuf);

    ...

    write(oFd, outBuf);

    ...
}
```

I've used this method a few times when I've needed to be able to handle a stream of data in a program that also needed to keep it's own STDIN or STDOUT for some reason.  The only tricky part comes if you wish myprog to be able to read data from the pipe that was written by two programs, as in:

```
cat afile > /dir/to_prog
cat anotherFile > /dir/to_prog
```

and have myprog be able to read both files.  The issue is that when the first cat exits it closes /dir/to_prog, and myprog will read this as an EOF.  A lot of programs interpret EOF as "no more data time to quit!" but in this case once the second cat starts myprog will be able to read more data from /dir/to_prog, it just has to know not to give up reading when it sees EOF.  And of course, if two programs write to a named pipe (or read from it) at the same time their data will be randomly interleaved.

Comment: great! this did it.

Comment: great answer, UP from me. I didn't think of named pipes.

Answer (score 3):

When your program is started as part of a pipe, the standard output of the
previous process is piped to the standard input of your program. So you just can
do:

```
int main(void)
{
    char line[1024];
    fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin);
    printf("First line is: %s\n", line);

    return 0;
}
```

On a POSIX system, you can use [`isatty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/isatty.3.html) to check if file descriptor belongs
refers to a terminal. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    if(isatty(STDIN_FILENO))
        puts("stdin connected to terminal");
    else
        puts("piped data to stdin");

    return 0;
}
```

The standard behaviour of programs is that they read from `stdin` and write to
`stdout`. By sticking to this, you can chain your programs using the shell's
pipe `|`.

For example `cat` expects to read from the standard input if no file is passed
as an argument. A simple implementation of cat would be:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    FILE *in = stdin;

    if(argc == 2)
    {
        in = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if(in == NULL)
        {
            perror("fopen");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
        fputc(c, stdout);

    if(in != stdin)
        fclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

Here as a programmer I don't really care when reading from `stdin` whether the
user types the input in the terminal, or whether the input is piped. The same
thing is true of writing to `stdout`. As a user I know that a program like `cat`
reads from `stdin` when no file is passed and it writes to `stdout`. Because
of this behaviour I can do

```
$ echo "hi" | cat | sort
```

So you should emulate this behaviour as well.

Of course, sometimes it is good to know if a pipe is involved. For example 
`git diff` writes to `stdout` with colors and without colors when you do
`git diff | more`. In such a case it's ok to check where `stdout` is connected
to, but the behaviour of writing to `stdout` is the same.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void print_colored_message(const char *msg)
{
    printf("\x1b[31m%s\x1b[0m\n", msg);
}

void print_message(const char *msg)
{
    if(isatty(STDOUT_FILENO))
        print_colored_message(msg);
    else
        puts(msg);
}

int main(void)
{
    print_message("Hello");
    print_message("World");

    return 0;
}
```

Copy & paste this program and execute it once as `./test` and once as `./test | less`.
You'll see that in the first version you get a colored output whereas in the
second version you don't. What remains constant is that the output was done on
`stdout`.

If you don't want your program to be chained in that way, then you have to tell
your users that they shouldn't use your program in such a chain.

Comment: What about the stdout side of things?

Comment: Just write to stdout. The standard behaviour, and what most programs expect, is that you read from stdin and write to stdout, end of story. It is the shell that knows how to connect stdin and stdout, either to a terminal or to pipe and the shell does that based on how you execute your program. If you execute `myprog`, then the shell will create a process and attach stdin to the termina. If you execute `echo hi | myprog` then the shell will connect stdin to the pipe. This is all maintained by the shell. You as a programmer should not worry about this things unless it is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

From BASH you can use the feature [temporary fifo](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63923/pseudo-files-for-temporary-data):

```
myapp <( nc localhost 1234 )
```

From C, if you want to read standard input as FILE pointer, well just use `stdin`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = stdin;
}
```

IF you want to redirect the output from custom command directly in C, use [popen](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html).